# How to tag a contact when importing possible duplicates

Tags: import, groups, duplicate-contacts, tags

I want to import a list of participants that attended an event and tag them and put them in a group.  Many of the names are already in the system so it doesn't import them based on the dedupe rule of names/emails. But I still want the existing names to be tagged and put in a specific group. I have the list of those not imported, how do I tag them and put them in a specific group for emailing purposes?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The *Import Contact* function can also help you to do this. Select the option *Update* for duplicate contacts.

[image: Use update in import]
In the last step of the import wizard, you can add a group or a tag to the imported (or updated) records. In the case you do not want to overwrite existing database values, you can create an import file that contains only the fields that you use to match.

Comment: Also if you want to import information about those not in the DB and not update those already in the db, then you can import all your attendees but set to SKIP, that way any contacts that do match will be given back to you as a list of 'errors' so you can then import them in a second round separately.

Comment: The method set out in this answer did not work for me when trying to import a list of contacts that already existed in the database. All I wanted to do was add a tag to the records, but Civi would not let me. I tried using the 'Update' and 'Fill' options, but neither worked.