# How to add a tag or group to a set of pre-existing contacts via import?

Tags: import, groups, tags, data-import

I have a list of contacts (names and email addresses). I know that all of these contacts are in the Civi database, but I want to add a tag or a group to all of them, and i have the list in a CSV file. What I should be able to do is simply import the contacts, setting 'Update' or perhaps 'Fill' as my duplicate matching option, and set the tag and/or group to be set in the import settings. Just tried it - several times, using various different options, and it failed every time, reporting that 0 records had been tagged (or added to the group). This is with Civi 4.7.19.

Is there a specific set of options that I need to know about to get this to work? This post ([How to tag a contact when importing possible duplicates](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-tag-a-contact-when-importing-possible-duplicates)) suggests that this should just work. I followed that example and it failed.

Comment: Hi Graham. Sounds odd. The only situation I know of where Tagging as the last step of an import is when a timeout issue happens (which is why i strongly advocate adding a custom field purely for the purposes of tracking the import process - and if you do that then you could do a search and Tag if the import tagging fails. But that is an extra step and should not be required. Did you confirm on Demo?

Comment: With the demo site I was successfully able to import a set of new contacts and add a new tag on import. If I then removed the tag from those contacts and ran a second import form the same file, using the 'update' option, and requesting that the tag be added on import, no tag was added.

Comment: Looks like this is linked to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20742

Comment: And https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20739

Comment: Couldn't you just use the api explorer?

Comment: @nielo - How would that work in this context?

Comment: I mean, as a workaround and if you don't want to code yourself, you could pass any id list (for instance imported contact ids) into api explorer and add a tag. 
Entity: Tag,
Action: Create,
[Your tag parameters],
Api-Chaining: EntityTag,
RefTable: Contacts,
RefIds in [your id list]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In my use case I didn't have IDs in my list of contacts. All I knew was that they were already in the database, so wanted to use the import to find them and tag them.

Comment: I see the bug report lists this as fixed, but I'm still experiencing it on version 4.7.22. @Graham, did the update resolve it for you?

Comment: Hi Erik. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20739 reports as fixed for 4.7.23 and that version is not yet released, so for the time being I'm still trying to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

To bypass this problem, I use Yes/No custom field to import the data "Belonging to A group". Then I use an advanced search to select those contacts and add them to the A group.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled across this bug - when a user already exists, trying to import and assign tags using the email/dedupe failed.

Mentioned in one of the jira issues https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20739 is "When performing a contact import using the "fill" option and using a dedupe rule to match (i.e. not including the contact ID in the import structure), the contacts will not be added to a group."

I found that if I import based on the contact ID, the additional tag was added - may not be a great solution for everyone but it's a workaround I can live with for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I face the same issue.

I tried many thing (import more than email for this 2nd import, change group visibility, use a new group, etc.) but it is still the same.

The import report always mentions "One contact added to this existing group."
But when I go to group panel, the group has no new contact.

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM are you working with Charles? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20739 was fixed in version 4.7.23 so if you are on an earlier version it might be worth updating and see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I confirm ! Problem solved by updating to CiviCRM 4.7.29